# Lich King raids are still available or disabled?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I absolutely missed all the Icecrown quests and most of all the quest to kill the Lich King. 
Are these quests still available after Cataclysm release?  Or would they disable them since it makes no sense chronologically?
If they are still there, are they 5-man or 10-man raids?  Do people still play them at all?  Can they be soloed now?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're all still available, even though they make no sense chronologically (as admitted by Blizzard).

All the dungeons are the same numbers as previously - 10 and 25 man for the ICC raid, and 5 man for Forge of Souls, Pit of Saron and Halls of Reflection.

They probably can't be soloed, but there would be very few people running them now that there's new content.

The only dungeons/raids removed as part of Cataclysm was Zul'Gurub, the old level 60 20 man.

Comment: Level 60 20 man? I really have been gone a while... last I knew it was a Level 60 40 man! When was this changed?

Comment: its been a looong time since 40 mans were dropped to 20/25

Comment: @Aeo: Zul Gurub was never a 40-man.  It was one of the few in Classic that wasn't.

Comment: Yes, Zul'Gurub and Ruins of Ahn'Qiraj (had to look that one up, only knew it as AQ20) were both 20 mans.  The remainder, including Temple of Ahn'Qiraj, were all 40 mans.

Comment: @Powerlord Well shoot... Guess that shows how foggy my memory is :P